# What's the point of unique_ptr?

Tags: pointers, c++11, memory, unique-ptr

Isn't a `unique_ptr` essentially the same as a direct instance of the object? I mean, there are a few differences with dynamic inheritance, and performance, but is that all `unique_ptr` does?

Consider this code to see what I mean. Isn't this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

void print(int a) {
    cout << a << "\n";
}

int main()
{
   unique_ptr<int> a(new int);
   print(*a);

   return 0;
}
```

Almost exactly the same as this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

void print(int a) {
    cout << a << "\n";
}

int main()
{
   int a;
   print(a);

   return 0;
}
```

Or am I misunderstanding what `unique_ptr` should be used for?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived)`...

Comment: @KerrekSB Yeah, i mentioned dynamic inheritance in my question. That seems to be one of the few things it's for though.

Comment: In your second example a copy is made of the `int`. This doesn't matter for `int` but for class types it does; the class may be non-copyable.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<T>` is not intended as a replacement for `T` but rather for `T*`.  If a `T` cuts it, there is no point in using a smart pointer.

Comment: @BWG: Handles for immovable resources are another example (e.g. mutexes, files, and things containing those). But even the polymorphism example is important; consider a factory `std::unique_ptr<AbstractCar> make_car(std::string model)`.

Comment: Another example: [pimpl (aka "compilation firewall")](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned, virtual classes are one use case. Beyond that, here are two others:

1. Optional instances of objects. My class may delay instantiating an instance of the object. To do so, I need to use memory allocation but still want the benefits of RAII.
2. Integrating with C libraries or other libraries that love returning naked pointers. For example, OpenSSL returns pointers from many (poorly documented) methods, some of which you need to cleanup. Having a non-copyable pointer container is perfect for this case, since I can protect it as soon as it is returned.

Comment: What's a "virtual class"?

Comment: a virtual class is a nested inner class whose functions and member variables can be overridden and redefined by subclasses of the outer class. Seems unrelated to unique_ptr

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of `std::unique_ptr` is to provide automatic and exception-safe deallocation of dynamically allocated memory (unlike a raw pointer that must be explicitly `delete`d in order to be freed and that is easy to inadvertently not get freed in the case of interleaved exceptions).

Your question, though, is more about the value of pointers in general than about `std::unique_ptr` specifically. For simple builtin types like `int`, there generally is very little reason to use a pointer rather than simply passing or storing the object by value. However, there are three cases where pointers are necessary or useful:

1. Representing a separate "not set" or "invalid" value.
2. Allowing modification.
3. Allowing for different polymorphic runtime types.

**Invalid or not set**

A pointer supports an additional `nullptr` value indicating that the pointer has not been set. For example, if you want to support all values of a given type (e.g. the entire range of integers) but also represent the notion that the user never input a value in the interface, that would be a case for using a `std::unique_ptr<int>`, because you could get whether the pointer is null or not as a way of indicating whether it was set (without having to throw away a valid value of integer just to use that specific value as an invalid, "sentinel" value denoting that it wasn't set).

**Allowing modification**

This can also be accomplished with references rather than pointers, but pointers are one way of doing this. If you use a regular value, then you are dealing with a copy of the original, and any modifications only affect that copy. If you use a pointer or a reference, you can make your modifications seen to the owner of the original instance. With a unique pointer, you can additionally be assured that no one else has a copy, so it is safe to modify without locking.

**Polymorphic types**

This can likewise be done with references, not just with pointers, but there are cases where due to semantics of ownership or allocation, you would want to use a pointer to do this... When it comes to user-defined types, it is possible to create a hierarchical "inheritance" relationship.   If you want your code to operate on all variations of a given type, then you would need to use a pointer or reference to the base type. A common reason to use `std::unique_ptr<>` for something like this would be if the object is constructed through a factory where the class you are defining maintains ownership of the constructed object. For example:

```
class Airline {
 public:
  Airline(const AirplaneFactory& factory);
  // ...
 private:
  // ...
  void AddAirplaneToInventory();
  // Can create many different type of airplanes, such as
  // a Boeing747 or an Airbus320
  const AirplaneFactory& airplane_factory_;
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Airplane>> airplanes_;
};

// ...
void Airline::AddAirplaneToInventory() {
  airplanes_.push_back(airplane_factory_.Create());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do know what pointers are used for. When I was looking at `unique_ptr`, I was thinking "cool, it's a RAII allocator/deallocator for pointers". But then I realized wrapping dynamic allocation/deallocation in RAII allocation/deallocation was stupid, except for a few edge cases, some of which you mention. I'm gonna accept Crhis's though, his answer is a little more to the point of what I'm asking.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to cases mentioned by Chris Pitman, one more case you will want to use `std::unique_ptr` is if you instantiate sufficiently large objects, then it makes sense to do it in the heap, rather than on a stack. The stack size is not unlimited and sooner or later you might run into stack overflow. That is where `std::unique_ptr` would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

A unique_ptr functions the same as a normal pointer except that you do not have to remember to free it (in fact it is simply a wrapper around a pointer). After you allocate the memory, you do not have to afterwards call delete on the pointer since the destructor on unique_ptr takes care of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to my mind:

- You can use it as a generic exception-safe RAII wrapper. Any resource that has a "close" function can be wrapped with `unique_ptr` easily by using a custom deleter.
- There are also times you might have to move a pointer around without knowing its lifetime explicitly. If the only constraint you know is uniqueness, then `unique_ptr` is an easy solution. You could almost always do manual memory management also in that case, but it is not automatically exception safe and you could forget to `delete`. Or the position you have to `delete` in your code could change. The `unique_ptr` solution could easily be more maintainable.